# Not able to rename an existing branch in Github. The EDIT branch option is not visible

Tags: github, branch, rename

I am stuck to rename an existing branch in Github. I have owner privilege. Still the Edit branch option is not coming. Though I can see the delete existing branch option.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Strange considering that, as documented in "[Renaming a branch](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/renaming-a-branch)":

> - People with write permissions to a repository can rename a branch in the repository.
> - People with admin permissions can rename the default branch.

Which means you should see, in the "list branches" page:

[image]